# Python Automation for Android

Tags: python, androidviewclient

I am trying to Use View-client as a pure python .. not as a Monkey-runner and trying to get a Automation framework for Android devices using "UI Automator" + "Dtmilano" .

Any help please .. How to use "UI Automator" + "Dtmilano"?? and disabling View-client as "Monkey-runner"??

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I'm understanding the question, but I guess you are asking how to use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) with **UiAutomator** backend.

**UiAutomator** is automatically selected by **AndroidViewClient/culebra** as the backend if

```
self.useUiAutomator = (version >= 16) and not forceviewserveruse
```

that is, if API >= 16 and you are not forcing the use of ViewServer.
Furthermore, **AndroidViewClient/culebra** is a pure python implementation so it does not depend on `monkeyrunner` since a long time ago.